# How to execute custom script when installing nuget package?

Tags: powershell, nuget

I created this project https://github.com/RemiBou/RemiBou.CosmosDB.Migration, for working it needs the user to do 2 things : create the appropriate folders and edit the csproj so the file inside those folders are embedded.

Before we could do that automaticly when installing with install.ps1 but this feature has been deprecated. Do you know any way how I could do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`install.ps1` isn't exactly deprecated, but it's a feature unique to `packages.config`. `PackageReference` has no concept of install as anyone can simply edit the `csproj` and add a PackageReference. When you restore, NuGet has no way of knowing if this is the first time the package is restored for the project after the reference was added, or if it's just the first time the project was restored with a clean repo (after a "msbuild /t:clean" or "git clone", for example).

I don't know an alternative for creating the folders other than having documentation that says the convention is to use that folder name. But, an alternative to modifying the csproj is to take advantage of the fact that MSBuild is a generic build system and NuGet packages can include [MSBuild props and targets file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#including-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package).

In your specific case, I would create a props file that defines a property something like `<RemiBouCosmosDBMigrationPath>CosmosDB\Migrations\</RemiBouCosmosDBMigrationPath>`, which allows your package users to change the property to a different path be overwriting the property value in their csproj, if they prefer.

Then create a targets file which contains a target something like

```xml
<Target name="RemiBouCosmosDBMigrationsEmbedMigrations" BeforeTargets="???">
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="$(RemiBouCosmosDBMigrationPath)**\*.js" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

You'll need to figure out what the best target name to put in the BeforeTargets attribute, but I hope you understand the idea. A `csproj` file is nothing more than a MSBuild file with certain conventions. MSBuild files can import other MSBuild files, and MSBuild and NuGet work together to allow MSBuild to import MSBuild files that come from restored packages. Just compose the MSBuild properties and items in a different way, and the end result can still be the same.

Comment: Hi @zivkan , even I am facing same kind of issue, while installing the nuget package the **PackageReference** gets update with lates version but Target's <Copy> didn't get update I have writtten an install.ps1 manually when i run this its working but when i keep it in .tagrets file **powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\install.ps1** it doesn't work could you please help me on this