# Run init.ps1 file after EACH NuGet installation

Tags: powershell, visual-studio, nuget-package

I have a C# NuGet project and I have created a `tools\init.ps1` file in order to perform some actions directly after the installation of the NuGet. This file is embeded using the `.nuspec` file of the NuGet project.

The fact is that I discovered that the script isn't run after **each** installation, and I discovered that the only trigger which allows the script to be started is that the NuGet should be installed after the Visual Studio re-opening.

For example:

- I open VS solution
- I select the target project ('*MyProject2*') and install my NuGet
- The script is successfully executed:

```
Added package 'MyProject.1.0.0' to folder 'C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\MySolution\packages'
Added package 'MyProject.1.0.0' to 'packages.config'
Executing script file 'C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\MySolution\packages\MyProject.1.0.0\tools\init.ps1'...
Successfully installed 'MyProject 1.0.0' to MyProject2
```

- I uninstall my NuGet in the project

> Successfully uninstalled 'MyProject.1.0.0' from MyProject2

- Install my NuGet again
- The script isn't executed:

```
    Added package 'MyProject.1.0.0' to folder 'C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\MySolution\packages'
    Added package 'MyProject.1.0.0' to 'packages.config'
    Successfully installed 'MyProject 1.0.0' to MyProject2
```

I don't find any way to run this script **after every installation** without restart Visual Studio. I have also tried to clear the NuGet cache before the uninstallation but the result is the same.

Is there any way, any option to activate, or something else, to be able to to that?

**[EDIT: after  *Mathias R. Jessen* comment]**

My .nuspec file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyProject</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <projectUrl>xxxxx</projectUrl>
    <description>MyProject provides a simple way to to something.</description>
    <copyright>Copyright ©</copyright>
    <readme>README.md</readme>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8" />
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.1" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="Bridge\*" target="lib\net48" />
    <file src="bin\Release\net48\MyProject.dll" target="lib\net48\MyProject.dll" /> 
    <file src="bin\Release\netstandard2.1\MyProject.dll" target="lib\netstandard2.1\MyProject.dll" /> 
    <file src="README.md" target="README.md" /> 
    <file src="tools\init.ps1" target="tools" />
  </files>
</package>
```

In addition, once the package is installed on the project, the package folder has the following content:

```
lib
tools
README.md
MyProject.1.0.0.nupkg
```

Comment: "This file is embeded using the .nuspec file of the NuGet project." - can you say more about how it's included in the .nuspec file? Perhaps share the relevant portion of the file, or at least tell us which schema directive you're using to reference the script?

Comment: I have edited my post in order to provide you the answer about how the file is carried by the package, and some information about the schema.

Comment: I'm no nuget expert, but [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54446743/712649) seems to suggest you can't reliably trigger anything at "install-time" because workflows associated with the `PackageReference` format (which I'm assuming you're using for your new .NET projects?) doesn't have an unambiguous "installation" phase